# Android ViewPager with PageTransformer looses it's Z-index

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-transitions

I have a question regarding crossfading on a viewpager where I have objects that depends on their z-layer. I found this topic [OnPageChangeListener alpha crossfading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433027/onpagechangelistener-alpha-crossfading/23526632#23526632) which provides the exact solution that I'm after except that the z-layers are ignored in the swiping, but only for the items on the left side, not the items on the right side.

[image]

First you can see the content on the left side, where the button is "cut" in half, next the transition, and, third, the item on the right side where the button is shown in its entirety. What I don't understand is why the button is only partly visible and what I need to do to make it fully visible?

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/sand">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="Hello World!" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

content_main_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:scaleType="center" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/background_part"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/sand"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/page_image"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/smaller" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/page_header"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/page_image"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
            android:text="Header Blue"
            android:lines="2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/page_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="Click me"
            />

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

My modified CustomPageTransformer:

```
  public class CustomPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

        public static final float ALPHA_VALUE = 0.8f;

        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
            View backgroundImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.background_color);

            View contentView1 = view.findViewById(R.id.item_container);

            if (position < -1) {
                // This page is way off-screen to the left
            } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
                // This page is moving out to the left

                if (backgroundImageView != null) {
                    // Fade the image in
                    backgroundImageView.setAlpha(ALPHA_VALUE + position);
                }

                // But swipe the contentView
                swipeContent(position, pageWidth, contentView1);

                // Counteract the default swipe
                view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
                // This page is moving in from the right

                // Counteract the default swipe
                view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

                swipeContent(position, pageWidth, contentView1);

                if (backgroundImageView != null) {
                    // Fade the image out
                    backgroundImageView.setAlpha(ALPHA_VALUE - position);
                }

            } else {
                // This page is way off-screen to the right
            }

            contentView1.bringToFront();
        }

        private void swipeContent(float position, int pageWidth, View view) {
            if (view != null) {
                view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * position);
            }
        }
    }
```

The initialization of viewpager and transformer looks like this:

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new CustomPageTransformer());
    pagerAdapter = new ItemPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

    pagerAdapter.setItems(items);
```

You can find the full source code [here](https://github.com/pernilla/ViewPagerSample).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging I changed the "contentView1" a little bit so I set the background on the viewpager and the contentView1´s background to transparent. I also set the level of ALPHA to 0.6f.

```
public static final float ALPHA_VALUE = 0.6f;
```

That made it a lot better.